# Running an application ON or UNDER Ubuntu?

Tags: language-support, spell-checking

What is the right expression?

*example 1:*

- This shows Thunderbird **on** Ubuntu.
- This shows Thunderbird **under** Ubuntu.

*example 2:*

- I run Octave **on** Ubuntu.
- I run Octave **under** Ubuntu.

Is there a difference? Why? And if there is difference: What is it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question will work better at [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use *in* or *on* Ubuntu. Never *under*. Under is for oppressive operating systems where the users are *under* lock and key, and where processes sometimes performs illegal instructions and must be placed *under* arrest.

Except for the connotative differences, *in*, *on* and *under* are all correct. But don't use *under*. We are over that. :)

But seriously; we refer to Ubuntu as a platform and an environment. You don't place things *under* a platform, but *on* it, and you don't place something *under* an environment, but *in* it. I see no good reason to use the word *under* in this context at all.

Comment: It's not so clear cut though. Some free operating systems use the term "under" in this way, sometime even in their official documentation. [Here's one example](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/configtuning-rcd.html); more can be found by searching the web. Words have multiple meanings and, in my opinion, there's no reason to think the negative connotations of "under" are ever applicable to operating systems.

Comment: As I wrote, there's nothing wrong with using "under", as it's been used for a long time. Linguistically, it's a very strange way to use that word. In what way are you running the program "Under FreeBSD"? I suppose it can stem from things being below the root. But I think most people will consider the kernel to sit at the bottom and everything else above it. If the kernel is on top, then it makes sense to use "under". You know, it's not _really_ that important. :)

Answer (score 2):

To be perfectly honest, I don't think there's any meaningful difference between the two. You can use whichever one you're most comfortable with.